# What's the error-signature from a socket.io response in SailsJS?

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I'm using SailsJS' default socket endpoints. E.g.:

```
socket.delete(url, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

now `response` can contain either the removed instance model or one of various kinds of errors.

What's a robust way to generically determine if an error was thrown or that all went ok? 
For instance, it seems that `statusCode` is passed for the errors I've encountered. Is `statusCode` guarenteed to be passed for **all** errors so that I can use this to discriminate between errors and non-errors?

BTW: perhaps this is more of a socket.io question than a SailsJS one, so I'll tag `socket.io` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of an adequate response to this question is precisely why the Sails socket client was [updated for version v0.10.x](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js).  Using the new library, the callbacks all have two arguments:

- `body` is equivalent to the response argument in the old socket client
- `response` is now a full HTTP-ish response object with a status code, headers and more.

The new library will work with Sails v0.9.x, but it will only provide the body, not the response.  To get the full monty you'll have to upgrade to Sails v0.10.x with `npm install sails@beta`.

Using the old library, you'll have to adopt your own standard for responses in order to detect status; things like `{status: '200', message: "it worked!"}` and `{status: '403', error: "forbidden"}` are typical.

Comment: I've read that this is how it should be in 0.10.x but I'm experiencing otherwise (The 0.9 behavior?). Please see https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1809 for an outstanding issue I've opened some days ago.

Comment: I've commented on that issue; mainly it's just a case of the docs being wrong and needing to be cleaned up.  If you have Sails v0.10.0-rc5 or higher, and the new socket client (from https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js), you should get the new behavior.